# How to check whether a sound file is playing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var soundObject = null;
function PlaySound() {
    var textvalue = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox7.ClientID %>').value;
    if (soundObject != null) {
        document.body.removeChild(soundObject);
        soundObject.removed = true;
        soundObject = null;
    }
    soundObject = document.createElement("embed");
    soundObject.setAttribute("src", textvalue);
    soundObject.setAttribute("hidden", false);
    soundObject.setAttribute("autostart", true);
    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(soundObject);
```

Above is my javascript code, TextBox7.text="c:\temp\abc.wav" in c#. I have two questions:
1. Is there anyway to tell whether the file c:\temp\abc.wax exists before playing the audio file?
2. How to check if the file start playing or not (since I put autostart)?

My intention is to alert user if the file does not exist or not playing?

PS: Actually, the program is working, it will play the audio when file exists and show a blackscreen if the audio file not found. I just want to make it better so that the user know what is going on.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Answer (score 0):

The `<embed>` element does not give you that level of control over the audio file being played. If you are able to, I would strongly encourage using the HTML5 `<audio>` element instead. It inherits from the `HTMLMediaElement` Dom interface which gives you access to a lot more media specific data. The `<embed>` element only inherits from the `HTMLElement` which does not give the same level of control.

You can change your above code to be:

```
soundObject = new Audio();
soundObject.src = textValue;
soundObject.hidden = true;
soundObject.autoplay = true;
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(soundObject);

soundObject.play();
```

Once you do that if you get an error on playback you can use `soundObject.error` to access the error message. This will give you an error if the file doesn't exist or any other error during playback.

To tell if the file is actively playing you can monitor the `soundObject.played` to see what part of the file has already been played.

I hope this solves your problem for you!

**Edit:**

I am attaching a JSFiddle that will hopefully give you a better idea of how to use this feature [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c63a8awv/).

Comment: The solution doesn't work for me, anyway, thanks for one and only one reply!

Comment: I am curious what about my solution isn't working for you. Do you have a javascript console up with any errors? I have used something similar to this (much more complicated, but same core concept) on a large scale project so I know the `Audio()` object works. If you are having problems instantiating the object in the script, try adding an `<audio>` tag to your div in the HTML and access via an ID. It might take a little tweaking for your use case, but it really will give you so much more control over the audio file.